# Install qt-creator doesn't run

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to install qt-creator on my computer (windows 8.1). I have this installation **qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline** but when I run it, nothing happens. The installation process won't start. I have tried installing **qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2012-x86_64-offline** which installs fine but the compiler is not stable. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by the "compiler is not stable"?

Comment: You should first try with [latest version, 5.2.1](https://qt-project.org/downloads). If that resolves the issue, then it was a Windows 8.1 specific bug in 5.1.1. I'd also first try with the online installer (just make sure that both the Qt libs for MinGW, *and* MinGW itself get installed, they're in separate branches of component tree in the installer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution. Turns out the installation file was corrupted. i download the same version from a different mirror and worked just fine. Thank you all for your comments and answers

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in the terminal and try running it again

sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libssl-dev libssl1.0 libgl1-mesa-dev libqt5x11extras5 '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev

Comment: an explanation of what your install code is doing would be useful, maybe more so when bumping a question asked 9 years ago.